# SAP for non SAPpers : change documents are collections of transports which are simply code deltas?

Tags: versioning, release-management, sap-solution-manager

I need to redact at functional level (pseudo code or specifications) a source code extraction routine which shall interact with SAP change management process (aka *ChaRM*), in order to obtain a copy of a certain environment, or part thereof, in order to be able to perform static code analysis prior to letting some code into target systems both on the extracted code as well as on any existing code within the same scope (that is having same object names).

I am facing a doubt regarding two *SAP-centric* concepts: **[change documents](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8b923a2175be4939816f0981b73856c7/7.2.04/en-US/71a7f315d1a344b6abf73e481db11254.html)** - which seems a recent addition to SAP when implementing ChaRM - and **[transport requests](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8b923a2175be4939816f0981b73856c7/7.2.04/en-US/60264ffa451548f9857f46423afdd1f1.html)**.

From what I understand change documents are collections of transport requests - where these are to be considered (from a functional standpoint) as "diff deltas": to obtain the resulting code on a certain target system, they have to be applied to existing code or environment.

Can I assume that change documents are just like groups of diff deltas which are grouped by convenience ?

This would allow me to describe the requirement as *"replay all change documents"* over a copy of the target environment so to obtain the resulting environment prior to affecting it.

cheers

Comment: `I am trying to define at a functional level a code extraction routine ` could you reword your question more clearly? what task are you trying to solve? SO is not a place for discussing concepts

Comment: Never heard about change documents but your assumptions on transport requests are correct. I don't know your exact requirements but to me it sound like you could use [abapGit](https://docs.abapgit.org/) to extract code from the affected SAP systems in a non-proprietary format, run your analysis on the extracted XML files and model changes as Pull Requests.

Comment: @konstantin : seems a good suggestion - althought it points to a tool which eases the description of the specifications but does not answer the question itself. PS: Change Documents is ChaRM specific - added to question context - and I am told a Change Document is a collection of transport requests with some metadata.